# I Can't See Who Created Grant Records

Tags: joomla, reports, grant

I cannot see who has created the grant records on any individual. Here sometimes the cancellation etc for the grant is going on in the registrations. Or you can enter more than one grant. But it is unclear who created these records. How can I get this information

For example: I created a grant for the person "A". The authorized person is checking this record. However, the data does not appear to indicate that the recording is mine or another person.

Answer (score 1):

Check in the civicrm_log table in the database and if there's an entry there for it then the modified_id will be the contact_id of the person who did it. But civicrm_log only logs minimal info. If you have detailed logging turned on at administer - system settings - misc, then there'll be a log_civicrm_grant table that records every change.

Comment: Hi @demerit, I checked the civicrm_log file. All records have modified_id information. This information is passed to the entity_table table as civicrm_grant. But the biggest problem is that I can't pull this information from the CiviCRM reports area. It is very difficult to access this data with a query from SQL. It also requires a permit.
In the meantime, I couldn't find a section called misc in System settings.

Comment: The menu entry's full name is "Misc (Undelete, PDFs, Limits, Logging, Captcha, etc.)" And yes you're right that currently there is no good way to access the info from the reports - you need to look at the SQL.

Comment: I found the menu. Thanks for more information. If I can't access this data on the CiviCRM Reports screen, my issue isn't solved. Checking through SQL will not be a solution for me at this time. Thank you for your interest.